# Which dmp file contains which tables

Tags: oracle, export, impdp

I have 3 tables that I want to import back (by impdp) into my database from the expdp-files-set of last night.

The expdp created 33 dump files.

Is there a way to check which file(s) contains my tables?

I have Oracle 11g on windows environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any reason for doing this, because one of impdp parameters is TABLES parameter where you can specify tables you want to import.

```
impdp ... TABLES=[schema_name.]table_name[:partition_name] ...
```

Source https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm#i1007036

Comment: 2 reasons: first - I dont want to write in the impdp command all the 33 files... sounds unnecessary. second - If I want to import it between databases... I prefer to not copy all of those files between 2 servers... (assuming I do not use an remote import)

Comment: Hmm, I see now. And what about setting DUMPFILE parameter to check file names against expression as mentioned here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm#i1006912 . Then setting TABLES parameter to specify tables you want to import. I would try this.